# flexible datetimepicker calendar (dayview) - month/year-selection (monthView) - only year-selection (yearview)

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

is there any javascript (jquery) datetimepicker which is flexible enough to do the following:

- show normal datetimepicker (returns selected date)
- show year / month picker (returns first of selected month)
- show year picker (returns first of year (1/1/2014)

I know you can disable many things in the jquery datetimepicker and there are many solutions out there but doesn't exist a easier way to perform this task with only one datetimepicker and change these things on the fly (year/month/day-view)?

btw: I have solved it with a dirty workaround - even so dirty I don't want to show a fiddle of it ;) - so I'm searching for a better solution.

thx

©a-x-i

Comment: I've forgotten to mention that for each view it exists a range view. In yearview from month to month. In monthview from day to day. And in dayview..... from time to time :)
So I also need a Timepicker too.
©a-x-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it will fit your needs, but you may try this one:
http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/

IMO, It has much better month/year select than jQuery UI Datepicker